# Windows Network Sharing - DHCP and Gateway pass through

Tags: windows, dhcp, gateway

I have several Windows 8 machines that are setup to do connection sharing over a wifi connection with switches behind a gigabit NIC. The devices behind the machines are Cisco phones and they are getting a 192.168.x.x address from the Windows machine.

I need to setup network-connected printers behind these machines, but the IP and gateway needs to come from the main gateway (10.8.x.x addresses) that is giving the Windows machine its DHCP lease and gateway.

What sort of settings will I need to add to the Windows machines to pass the devices behind the switch over to the main gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 ICS doesn't offer much space for configuration. If you aren't satisfied with the default all-in-one DHCP+DNS+default gateway+NAT solution, Microsoft requires you to buy and use Windows server (or you could use Linux).

Alternatively, you can maybe configure your network to do bridging between ethernet and wireless, but then your network configuration would be pretty different and maybe not applicable.

Comment: If you can control the main gateway while you want to keep the configuration on window machines as static as possible the bridge solution could be the best idea.